# Nonparametric vs. Parametric tests

Tags: data, methodology, data-analysis

I work as a UX Researcher for a mobile gaming company.

We're discussing best practices in analysis, and my colleague suggested that we *always* use nonparametric tests (e.g., Mann-Whitney U rather than t, Kruskall-Wallace rather than ANOVA) because they do not suffer from the violation of assumptions that parametric tests do.

I've only ever used nonparametrics if I *had* to (e.g., the data were counts or ranks rather than means). The argument that one should *always* use nonparametrics doesn't sit well with me, but I certainly haven't done exhaustive research on the subject.

Are there any guidelines as to when we should use parametrics vs nonparametric tests?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure this is type of discuss is on topic for UX.SE. But nonparametric tests are less powerful. Your first step should be to be visually inspect the data to see how it's distributed, then you decide what tests to use.

Comment: I think I need help understanding this forum!  I've only posted three questions, and they've all been inappropriate for UX.SE.  It might be that this isn't the community I'm looking for, or that I'm using it wrong.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: I suggest taking the [TOUR] to get an better understanding. And your first lesson - Stack Exchange is not a forum. It's a Q&A site.

Comment: I asked a Q, didn't I?  I wasn't treating it like a discussion forum.

Comment: Hi @SamuraiUX - I think the close vote was made because your question is looking for opinions. On a Q&A site the best questions have a *correct* answer, versus a collection of "I think..." type answers. Would rephrasing your question something like "Under what conditions is 'this' test best used versus 'that' test?" still be in the spirit of what you're looking for?

Comment: please note that "one should always use nonparametrics" is not an argument, but a proposition. the argument for it is "they do not suffer from the violation of assumptions that parametric tests do". do you have any arguments against it? do you think they don't violate the assumptions (whatever they are) or that the violations are not serious enough to make the conclusions meaningless?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey... I assume there IS a correct (or correct-ish) answer to this question.  There are many ways to do statistics; if your statement were true, that would mean I could and never should ask any questions about data analysis here.  I'm super-confused b/c many questions on this site are equally (or MORE) opinion-oriented than mine (just for one e.g., see http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4468/is-user-testing-a-luxury-or-a-necessity?rq=1).  I guess I asked a question that no one knows enough stats to answer?  Or I'm too new to be allowed this type of question?  It's perplexing.

Comment: @Aprillion, sure the argument against is "they lack the power of parametric tests."  ... I just wish people here would answer my questions more and scold me about the validity of my questions less.  If people aren't statistically savvy enough to have a useful answer, that's fine, but then move on to another question you CAN answer instead of telling me I'm doing it all wrong (here I'm not addressing you personally, Aprillion.  Just people here in general).

Comment: if you accept that they viokate assumptions and thus cannot be used, what good does it do them if they were more powerful? it is unclear what you are asking because you didn't actually ask any questions.

Comment: I agree that there is a correct(-ish) answer, and an "-ish" answer is perfectly fine here. I think there is an edit that can be done to that would pass through moderation on a re-open vote! Right now you're asking for opinion, which *might* have been why it was put on hold. Another idea for rephrasing the question could be to think of it in terms of a teacher to a class. The teacher isn't going to ask for open opinion, they're going to ask for the pros/cons - there is still flexibility in the correctness of an answer, but it frames the question towards a goal versus an open discussion.

Comment: Do mobile gaming company also discuss ethics as part of best practice?

Comment: Voted to close. I think that this is actually a good question and it SHOULD be on-topic, but it seems like we don't get many people with a professional-level grasp of statistics on this site (myself included, unfortunately). It is definitely a BETTER fit on http://stats.stackexchange.com/, I think that the best thing is to migrate there.

Comment: Thank you all, for the discussion.  I think I will try stats.stackexchange as Vitaly suggested, but will return for issues more clearly of the UX nature!

Comment: @MichaelLai, we do, of course.  We're not APA regulated, but that doesn't mean we don't care. ;)  Why do you ask?

Comment: Also, I added back in my "thank you."  I imagine people don't mind me being grateful for their contribution. =/  No need to be impolite in the name of being concise.

Comment: I am not suggesting that UX people don't care, but I am curious that in the area of mobile gaming where conflicts because revenue and user experience seem to work against each other. I asked a question about repetitive strain injury prevention in mobile applications and no one provided an answer...

Comment: I *can't* answer that question b/c I don't know enough about repetitive strain injuries and UX Design (I'm a UX Researcher).  But I'd imagine we're about as concerned about it as everyone else in the app store (read: almost no one, probably).=/

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that there aren't more people responding to this question because there is definitely a need for more rigour around statistical analysis in usability testing.

I think you'll find some good resources from Jeff Sauro from [MeasuringU](https://www.measuringu.com/about.php), who seems to be one of the people that does a lot of consulting work in this area. I like most people, know little about statistics but at least I don't believe any stats I get without knowing how the figures were produced.

For me there is a more important thing compared to deciding the type of statistical analysis that you use to get your p-value - it should be about whether you've asked the right question in the first place, and whether your answer can be validated in more than one way. That's where the power of statistics come into the fore, being able to add some analysis and decision process to your decisions, but not be the reason for making those decisions.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of applied research analysis, it's wise to avoid choosing a blanket approach. As @Michael Lai mentioned, your hypothesis / research question should drive your choice of statistical method and Jeff Sauro's blog is a good resource. (I'll avoid my tirade about the lack of real hypothesis testing in UX research for later because it sounds like you ARE testing hypotheses in your role.)

That said, there are some underlying assumptions about your data that dictate whether you should use parametric over nonparametric approaches. The rule of thumb that I was taught (in several stats courses) in graduate school is that if you have interval data as your dependent variable, use parametric tests. Like you mention, if you are measuring categorical, rank, or some forms of choice data as your outcome, then you should use a nonparametric test.

ANOVA specifically is *extremely* robust to violations of assumptions of normality and equal variance (the two that I feel we know the least about in UX studies, so are most likely to violate). Further, there are several *types* of ANOVA that were derived to allow more flexibility in research design and handle interval data that violate core assumptions (e.g. MANOVA, ANCOVA).

So, no. You should NOT just use nonparametric tests in UX research. Use the tool that's appropriate for the job.